# If I delete a constraint my table view cells become blank

Tags: ios, constraints

I have 2 images, a label and a button in my table view cells and if I delete a vertical spacing constraint between the label and the content view, the table view cells become blank when i run my app.

Do you know why?

Comment: Let me check my crystal ball.

Comment: Most probably theirs constraint are incomplete and therefore, their runtime frame are different.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave just "some" constraints your UI will probably be garbage.

Either clear all constraint

```
Editor > Resolve AutoLayout Issues > Clear Constraints
```

or let the system set them for you

```
Editor > Resolve AutoLayout Issues > Reset to Suggested Constraints
```

But **NEVER** delete them unless you **know** what you are doing